# Как называют человека, перешедшего из одной религии в другую?

Tags: одним-словом

**Как называют человека, перешедшего из одной религии в другую?** Пример: татарин, отказавшийся от ислама и прошедший крещение в православной церкви.

Я нигде не смог найти ответа, как ни искал.

В английском для этого есть существительное *convert* (произносится не /kənˈvərt/, а /ˈkänˌvərt/).

Comment: я бы рекомендовал предложенный тут (и нейтральный) термин "новообращённый".

Comment: Смотря кто называет. Есть ещё слово "ренегат". Смысл отрицательный .

Comment: Апостат, вероотступник :)

Comment: В случае татар есть [кряшены](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B), но не уверен, что корректно так будет назвать татарина только на основании смены религии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Конверти́т](http://endic.ru/gallicism/Konvertit-9947.html).**

Редкое слово, возможно, с налетом архаичности, но означает именно это.

Comment: Много ли реальных примеров использования ? :>

Answer (score 7):

Для людей, перешедших из какой-либо другой религии в христианство, как в вашем примере, существует устаревшее название «выкрест».

Answer (score 6):

Слово ["прозелит"](https://azbyka.ru/prozelit) в узком смысле обозначало человека, перешедшего из язычества в иудаизм (а позже и в христианство) со временем стало обозначать в принципе новообращённого (это слово, новообращённый, уже упомянуто в другом ответе). Есть ещё близкое по значению слово ["неофит"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82), но неофит не обязательно должен быть приверженцем чего-то нового в религиозном смысле, так что, если из контекста это не ясно, можно уточнить, и сказать "религиозный неофит".

Keep in mind that another word mentioned, "выкрест" (though the answer is valid) is obsolete and offensive. Also, "выкрест" is not necessarily recently conversed.

Comment: What could possibly be offensive about the word выкрест?

Comment: @OmarL, about the same as with the word "ренегат": it implies, in the first place, "deserting" one's former faith. Even if that person comes to "our" faith, people tend(ed) to view such persons as inauthentic and/or potential traitors. Besides, there doesn't have to be a reason: it is sufficient that the word is perceived as such. What could possibly be offensive about the word "Negro"?

Answer (score 4):

[Новообращённый](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) / новообращенец?